# Linux installation on docker over windows host machine

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on windows 7, and i want to build several components inside that virtual environment.So, after the basic set up of docker i have to install linux on that and add further components. I read some where that linux cannot be installed over windows, is that true ?

Comment: you need vmware or virtualbox installed first. Go through with Docker installation webpage https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/

Comment: Yes I have installed virtual box and then set up the docker environment.